# Groovy script doesn't know messageExchange

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm using Ready!Api, new soupui interface. 
What I'm doing is making a script that will compare the response XML with a textfile. The result will be writtin in another file(but, not there jet).

I found a nice script on github (https://gist.github.com/karlin/789830) what I'm altering.

Now, I get a message that the MessageExchange isn't a valid property. As a workaround I start using: `com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.MessageExchange`
e.g.

```
compareWithExpected(context,com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.MessageExchange)
```

The variable passed is `mex` in the def. 
When I use `mex.responseContentAsXml`  I get the next message:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: responseContentAsXml for class: com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.MessageExchange Possible solutions: responseContentAsXml error at line: 10

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried just `mex.responseAsXml`?

Comment: It was a dumb newby error. the messageexchagne only works in a assertion. I tried to use it in a script... it is working now, thanks